# stat() not working properly?

Tags: c, ubuntu, stat

What am I doing wrong here, or is there something wrong with Ubuntu 12.04 (latest patches)?  Generally I am writing a piece of SUID code to do a bit of this, bit of that, and for security reasons I would like to make sure the file the program targets is a regular file, not something else, most notably symlink.

```
visti@honecker:~/Project/Images$ ls -al
total 3080
drwxrwxr-x 2 visti visti    4096 May 29 14:18 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 visti visti    4096 May 29 14:42 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 visti visti      10 May 29 14:18 foo -> image-ntfs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 visti visti 3145728 May 28 16:17 image-ntfs
```

I have here a directory with a regular file and a symlink to the file. In my opinion stat() should be able to distinguish between these two but it isn't:

```
main (int argc, char **argv) {
  int i;
  struct stat buf;
  if (argc < 2) 
    exit(1);
  for (i = 1; i < argc ; i++) {
    if (stat (argv[i], &buf) == -1) {
      perror("foo");
      exit(1);
    }
    printf ("%s,%d\n", argv[i], buf.st_mode & S_IFMT);
  }
}
```

And when I run the compiled program against the directory, this is what I get. Both of the files have only S_IFREG set. What am I doing wrong?

```
visti@honecker:~/Project/Images$ ../stat *
foo,32768
image-ntfs,32768
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to use `lstat()` instead of `stat()` if you want to do stat on symbolic link itself.

`man stat` has

> lstat() is identical to stat(), except that if path is a symbolic
>   link,
>   then the link itself is stat-ed, not the file that it refers to.

Comment: Also, it sounds as if your code is open to a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) if it uses `lstat()` to *first* validate something, then doing that something. If someone swaps the validated file with a "dangerous" symlink between those two steps, the check has been fooled.